# My docker container was created with no name and no tag

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm creating a docker image for hakyll compilation. Here's the dockerfile:

```
FROM haskell:7.10

RUN cabal update && cabal install hakyll
```

This file is in some folder on my D: drive: `D:\Haskell\docker\docker-hakyll`.

I'm using Boot2Docker on Windows to build it. `docker images` gives me

```
REPOSITORY TAG    IMAGE ID     CREATED VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>     <none> 195a730d8827 33 minutes ago  1.464 GB
haskell    7.10   11849cc2a27b 3 days ago      716.2 MB
```

`docker build .` does

```
Step 0 : FROM haskell:7.10
---> 11849cc2a27b
Step 1: RUN cabal update && cabal install hakyll
---> 195a730d8827
Successfully built 195a730d8827
```

Anyone have a clue? How can I `docker run` this? Or even rename it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it. I can supply a name with `docker build -t NAME .`.

Comment: and you can run it with the id `docker run  195` (add the appropriate flags, like `-it -d`or anything that applies